# Live streaming with DSLR video cameras that have time-out recording

Tags: dslr, live, live-recording, time

DSLRs, unlike camcorders, are often made to stop recording when a certain amount of minutes, like 35, passes since first pressing the record button. What's the point of this?

Does this rule hold for people who live-stream on Twitch, for example, using DSLRs? Streamers go for hours on end without touching the camera, so how do they do it? When they first purchase their camera are they actually looking for a feature that bypasses the time-out rule or something, what is it called

Comment: Welcome! The record length restriction is a business decision made by the manufacturers to get around (possibly outdated) [tariff classifications](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-compact-cameras-with-no-video-length-limit).

Comment: i see, how about the second question about how live streamers select their equipment and stream for infinite lengths of time